# How do I push my json data to either a in memory database or a pojo

Tags: json, database, firebase, spring-boot

I am working on a project where I get a json from firebase, and I want to end up creating a table and graphs using this data, but I'm not too sure if itll be easy to work with json vs querying from a database to dynamically load a table and a graph. I dont know if i should make Pojo's or store the information into a in memory java database. The json values are dynamic, so it's pretty hard to figure out how to parse through it

i tried implementing the h2 dependancy, but got a lot of errors there since the title of the json will be dynamically created

```
{
  "Work Order: Optional(\"buv\")": {
    "Manager Name": "John Guy",
    "Technician Name": "Hussein N",
    "When": "Completed Job",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "YES"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "Reason3": "Planner Scheduler and/or Supervisor\nnotified about work order status",
      "Work order process was followed?": "NO"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Bububj ",
      "Reason2": "SOW was changed/altered, SOW\nunachievable by technician",
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "NO",
      "pic1": "https://firebasestorage....
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "N/A"
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"h\")": {
    "Manager Name": "Jay S",
    "Technician Name": "Jasmine S",
    "When": "Completed Job",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "YES"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Work order process was followed?": "YES"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "YES"
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "YES"
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"huss1\")": {
    "Manager Name": "Navendra Mahatra Shivani Panday",
    "Technician Name": "qhhg",
    "When": "qhhgh",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Gigi ",
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "N/A"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Work order process was followed?": "YES"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Hihihihi",
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "N/A",
      "pic1": "https://firebasestorage....
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Nono",
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "NO",
      "Reason2": "Labor time entries made appropriately"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Hihihi",
      "Reason1": "Signs of work debris residue (i.e. stains,\nclippings, soils, zip ties, dust, drips, spills,\nfingerprints)",
      "Reason2": "Appropriate/proper tool(s) used for\nthe job",
      "Reason3": "Appropriate material used and/\nor requested",
      "Reason4": "The quality of work portrayed trade\nstandard specifications (i.e. shape, cut,\nlevel, plumb, slope/grade, finish, sound)",
      "Reason5": "Material was incorrectly ordered/\ndelivered (this option will reflect on the\nmaterial/service provider)",
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "NO",
      "pic1": "https://firebasestorage.googleap...
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"q\")": {
    "Manager Name": "q",
    "Technician Name": "q",
    "When": "q",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "YES"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Work order process was followed?": "YES"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "YES"
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "YES"
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"rh\")": {
    "Manager Name": "Jay S",
    "Technician Name": "Amy V",
    "When": "Completed Job",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "YES"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Work order process was followed?": "YES"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "YES"
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "YES"
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"snsns\")": {
    "Manager Name": "Navendra Mahatra Shivani Panday",
    "Technician Name": "Kunjan B",
    "When": "Completed Job",
    "firstPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "N/A"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "Work order process was followed?": "N/A"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "Dkggjfj\n",
      "Reason1": "Work being performed/completed\nmatches the description of the work order\ndetails",
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "NO",
      "pic1": "https://firebasestorage.googleap...
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "YES"
    }
  },
  "Work Order: Optional(\"test3\")": {
    "Manager Name": "Bob Smith",
    "Technician Name": "Jasmine S",
    "When": "During job",
    "fifthPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "Appropriate PPE was used for the work order?": "NO",
      "Reason2": "Appropriate size of PPE for work being\nperformed/completed"
    },
    "firstPage": {
      "Technician had professional presentation?": "YES"
    },
    "fourthPage": {
      "Work order process was followed?": "YES"
    },
    "secondPage": {
      "Additional Comments": "",
      "Reason1": "Work being performed/completed\nmatches the description of the work order\ndetails",
      "Scope of work (SOW) was accurately achieved?": "NO"
    },
    "sixthPage": {
      "Job site was presented to be a safe work zone?": "YES"
    },
    "thirdPage": {
      "The work performed was of Stanford,Facilities Operations and Trade Specific quality?": "YES"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Jackson to your project and use it to create a POJO instance with your JSON data as such:

```
//JSON from file to Object
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);

//JSON from String to Object
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
```

Jackson maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you added user but what is user?
ALso what is mapper

Comment: User is just an example of a pojo. I do not know what kind of data you have,  but just create your own pojo with all the fields from your JSON, then replace "User" with your own POJO name

Comment: could you post another solution to this because isn't really working for me...